# Retrieve a unique identifier from MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, concurrency, unique, counter

I've got a web application (JSP/Tomcat on MySQL) that offers the functionality to fill an online contract and needs to return at the end a unique counter or identifier to the client as a protocol for the contract. If two clients confirm the form at the same time the SELECT MAX(COUNTER) on db doesn't safeguard against identifier conflicts.

I've got a table that keeps track of the next identifier available for client for each type of contract:

```
CONTRACT_TYPE   COUNTER
A                    21 
B                    13
```

The method to get the next identifier is:

```
public int getNewCounter(String contractType) {
    query1 = SELECT (COUNTER + 1) AS NEW_COUNTER from mytable WHERE CONTRACT_TYPE = 'A'
    query2 = UPDATE mytable SET COUNTER = <counter_returned_on_previous> WHERE CONTRACT_TYPE = 'A'
    return NEW_COUNTER;
}
```

This has the problem that concurrent clients can potentially receive the same identifier if they submit the form in the same moment and this is what I would like to avoid.

In other words with 2 concurrent clients this can happen:

```
client1-query1
client1-query2
client2-query1
client2-query2
```

that is the right behaviour but I can have also this:

```
client1-query1
client2-query1
client1-query2
client2-query2
```

resulting in identifier value conflict. What is the best way to permit multiple clients to have some kind of "exclusive access" to the two queries above in order to garantee that a unique identifier is returned by the function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `UPDATE mytable SET counter = counter+1 WHERE contract_type =  'A'`

Comment: *unique COUNTER is assigned to each client?* why counter should be unique?

Comment: Because counter rapresents a protocol number on the contract

Comment: so why did you call column `counter` but not `protocol_number` ?

Comment: The name is because it starts from 1 and goes ahed like a counter. Btw I think that your first solution has the some issue because after UPDATE the application needs to read the value and only one client should do it before the next update. I found an option in MySQL called SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE  but I don't kwow if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: did you try my solution? or you just guessing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 queries.

Solution is as simple as:

```
UPDATE table1 SET counter = counter+1 WHERE contract_type = 'A';
```

You can play with [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/183cd/1)

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question. The task of generating a unique identifier in MysSQL in a concurrent environment can be accomplished in 2 ways:

1) Using an InnoDB table with transaction and the SELECT FOR UPDATE locking mode:

```
START TRANSACTION (or set autocommit to 0);     
SELECT COUNTER FROM mytable WHERE contract_type = 'A' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE mytable SET COUNTER = COUNTER + 1 WHERE contract_type = 'A';     
COMMIT;
```

A SELECT ... FOR UPDATE reads the latest available data, setting exclusive locks on each row it reads.

2) With a single access to the table:

```
 UPDATE myTable SET COUNTER = LAST_INSERT_ID(COUNTER + 1) WHERE contract_type = 'A';
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The fashion here is that the SELECT statement merely retrieves the identifier information (specific to the current connection). It does not access any table!

Source:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html